# Is there an easier way to append a slice of structs?

Tags: go

The following code works, but I want to find a simpler way to do it

```
package main

import "fmt"

type steps []struct {
    i int
    j int
}

func main() {
    steps := steps{}
    type step struct{ i, j int }
    steps = append(steps, step{1, 1}, step{1, 2})
    fmt.Println(steps)
}
```

Specifically, I don't want to define a new type just so I can append it to a slice. For example, I want to do it like this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type steps []struct {
    i int
    j int
}

func main() {
    steps := steps{}
    steps = append(steps, {1, 1}, {1, 2}) // syntax error
    fmt.Println(steps)
}
```

But I'll get a "syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression"

I don't understand why I can't do it this way, the data structure is correct.

Comment: "I don't understand why I can't do it this way" --- because it's incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an anonymous struct in your slice, so you need to repeat the schema when adding elements:

```
// works - but a bit tedious...
steps = append(steps,
        struct {
            i int
            j int
        }{1, 1},
        struct {
            i int
            j int
        }{1, 2},
)
```

or define the sub-type:

```
type step struct {
    i int
    j int
}
type steps []step

steps = append(steps, step{3, 4}, step{5, 6})
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Xw42P7IlONf)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - updated to include the more `go` way

Comment: @oNion BTW anonymous struct definitions are very handy in some cases, for test-tables and also one-time [template uses](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#2)